# Prove that the centre of a circle belongs to a defined line

Tags: geometry

In the picture $\Delta ABC$ angle A equals 60 degrees, AD is a bisector of BC. DF is perpendecular to BC. The angle FDA equals the angle FDE. How can I prove that the point E coincides with the  centre of circumscribed circle in the triangle ABC?

(In other words we have to prove that the centre of the circle belongs to DE)

[image]

Comment: $AD$is a bisector of what?

Comment: Of $\angle CAB$

Comment: @student28 Are we given $\angle FDE$?

Comment: A bisector of angle BAC.

Comment: No, we are not. it is just to show equality.

Comment: Actually you can only prove that the center is on the line through $D$ and $E,$ not that it is specifically at $E.$ So rather than saying one thing which is not provable and then "in other words" a second thing, just say the second thing.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

Bisector $AD$ intersects arc $BC$ at its midpoint $H$, and so does the perpendicular bisector of side $BC$ (see diagram below, where $O$ is the circle center). The required angle equality is equivalent to proving that triangle $ODH$ is isosceles, which in turn is a consequence of $OCH$ being an equilateral triangle.

[image]